# Javascript global var is accessible in IE but not in MOZILLA Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am using tile in my application which has the following layout (in Main JSP)

1. Header part (Same throughout app)
2. Body part   (Body content that get changes for different pages )
3. Footer part  (Same throughout app)

Body Part - will change with x.jsp or y.jsp

The idea is Script in Header should be executed in y.jsp and not in x.jsp

In the Header View(jsp) I have script that will access global var defined in `x.jsp` script so that the script in header identifies that body part has `x.jsp` and not `y.jsp`.

for eg Header script

```
    if(type of (flag)=="undefined"){

        \\\then execute the script
    }  
   else{

        \\\dont execute the script
    }
```

Note - this flag `var` will be in `x.jsp` and will not be defined `y.jsp`

**This works well in IE** But isn't working in Firefox.

Comment: Are you really asking for JavaScript? Looks like this is a serverside task. If not, please post the (relevant parts of the) generated HTML markup with your scripts that work in IE

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, it's `typeof`, not `type of`, but then again, are you really working with javascript?

JSP files run on the server.
Javascript runs on the client (i.e. in the browser).

As it seems, you do at least *something* clientside, because something works in IE and not in Firefox, but I doubt it has to do with the problem you describe above.

Comment: Friend i understand the differences between server side and client side .. but i have already mentioned that logic for executing SCRIPT is working fine in IE but not in FIREFOX. It is JAVASCRIPT only ..anyways I have mentioned about the JSP to give the context of app architecture. Please help..

Comment: Then the problem description is wrong. You're only describing how JSP is doing something serverside, but then the problem is with the Javascript code clientside, of which code you don't show any.

Comment: There is not much javascript coding to brief you but still i will give it try.
Script in Header.jsp will perform the check for global var is defined or not using 

if typeof globalvar

Comment: There is not much javascript coding to brief you but still i will give it try.
Script in Header.jsp will perform the check for global var which will be initialized in one of the body part of the page x.jsp.
  
so that when y.jsp is loaded along with header.jsp the var remains undefined and when x.jsp is loaded with header.jsp the var is defined
Note - Header.jsp + body.jsp(x or y) +Footer.jsp makes one HTML page
There are script in Header and body (x or y).
The x.jsp initializes the var in the script but script in y.jsp doesnt.
Is it clear? & note that logic is working on IE but not in Mozilla

Comment: You repeat the problem, but you still don't show any Javascript code, so we cannot figure out what's wrong with it. Just leave out the part about JSP's, and show us the stuff that is sent to the browser. *Then* ask what's wrong with that output.